# Not able to Create Continuous Export for Telemetry AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Working on Application Insights for a web api. Trying to Create continuous Export for telemetry and trace, so as to save the trace in a BLOB or Power BI. But not able to Select "Add" in Continuous Export as it is disabled.

I have created storage account and also container.

I have a "Visual Studio Enterprise" subscription.

Do you have any idea how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MSDN and Visual Studio Azure subscriptions you need to remove the spending limit since continuous export is s paid feature that is not available for use with developer credits.

The second link has details in the QnA at the bottom.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-spending-limit

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/application-insights/